# Courant. Real numbers determined by nested sequences of rational intervals.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

In his book Introduction to Calculus and Analysis vol.1, page 95 Courant writes:

Every nested sequence of intervals with real end points contains a real number. To prove this, consider closed intervals $[x_n, y_n]$, each interval contained in proceeding one, whose lengths $y_n-x_n$ form a null sequence. We claim there is a real x contained in all $[x_n, y_n]$. To prove this we replace the nested sequence $[x_n, y_n]$ by a nested sequence of rational intervals $[a_n, b_n]$, containing $[x_n, y_n]$. The rational sequence will then define the desired real number x. For each n let $a_n$ be the largest rational number of the form $p / 2^n$ less than $x_n$, and $b_n$ the smallest of the form $q / 2^n$ greater than $y_n$, where p and q are integers. Clearly, the intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ form a nested sequence representing the real number x. If x lay outside one of the intervals $[x_m, y_m]$, say $x<x_m$ there would exist a rational $r$ with $x<r<x_m$, whence for all sufficiently large n we would have
$$y_n<=b_n<r<x_m<=x_n$$ which is impossible.

The question: why should in this case this rational number r be larger as $b_n$ or $y_n$ ?

Comment: Part of your text is not visible because `<` is interpreted as the beginning of an html tag. Enclosing your formulas in dollars makes them display better. Consult this guide to get started with formatting: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = x$ and $x < r$ you have $b_n < r$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Each of x_n and y_n is monotone, thus convergent. If they converge to different values the length converges to a positive value, a contradiction. Thus they both converge to the same value. This value however is never achieved because then the next interval couldn't exist. Thus it is within each interval.